# I did a software update & now I can't open Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I get the following message when I try to open mail

'You can't use this version of Mail with this version of Mac OS x
You have Mail version 4.5 (1084/1085). It can't be used on Mac OS X version 10.6.8 )build 10k549)'

I have read the help info

I have made sure Mail.app is in the application folder

Thanks for any help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state Mail.app is already in the Applications folder, follow [these additional steps](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203684):

1. Download [Safari 5.1.7](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1569) for Snow Leopard
2. [Reinstall](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399) the Mac OS X Update v10.6.8 Combo v1.1
3. Reinstall Safari 5.1.7 for Snow Leopard
4. [Reinstall](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1586) Security Update 2012-004

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel my answer resolved your question, please feel free to click on the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This means Mail, for some reason or another, did not upgrade. Try extracting it from the Installer package or copy it from another computer with the *same Mac OS X version* (not reccomended, as permissions can change.)

Answer (score -1):

Somehow, you made a copy of the old Mail.app and it is starting instead of the version in the Applications folder. Control-click on the Mail icon in the dock, then select **Options** and **Show in Finder**. This will show you the old version that is no longer supported.